# CLR Crash when Marshalling from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling, unmanaged

I am making use of an API from Nikon to control a microscope. The API is written in C++ while I am implementing a driver in C#. To open a connection with the microscope, I must use an Open method with the following Syntax:

```
lx_result MIC_Open ( const lx_int32 iDeviceIndex, lx_uint64& uiConnectedAccessoryMask, const lx_uint32 uiErrMsgMaxSize, lx_wchar* pwszErrMsg)
```

If I marshal the technique as follows, the code crashes whenever a Garbage Collection is performed:

```
[DllImport("/filepath/Ni_Mic_Driver.dll")]
protected static extern int MIC_Open ( int deviceIndex , ref ulong accessoryMask , uint errorMessageMaxSize , [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string error);
```

A 0xc000005 exception is thrown with error code 80131506, indicating the Garbage Collector has attempted to dispose of an object with an invalid pointer. An error message produced by Visual Studio 2013 indicates:

"This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code.
Common sources of this bug include user marshalling errors for COM-Interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

Following the messages advice, I adjusted the marshalling to the following, which results in no CLR crash.

```
[DllImport("/filepath/Ni_Mic_Driver.dll")]
protected static extern int MIC_Open ( int deviceIndex , ref ulong accessoryMask , uint errorMessageMaxSize , [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string error);
```

I am confused because it is my understanding that wchar* indicates a pointer to a string of null-terminated 16-bit Unicode characters, which should map to UnamagedType.LPWStr. However, the code works only if I use UnmanagedType.LPStr.

The following also works, but should require more work to then extract the corresponding string.

```
[DllImport("/filepath/Ni_Mic_Driver.dll")]
protected static extern int MIC_Open ( int deviceIndex , ref ulong accessoryMask , uint errorMessageMaxSize , IntPtr errorPointer );
```

Any thoughts on why UnamagedType.LPWStr would cause the crash while it behaves with UnmanagedType.LPStr or IntPtr?

Comment: What does `MIC_Open` do with the pointer? Does it attempt to free it, or does it hold on to it after it returns? I should also point out that marshaling `lx_uint64&` as a pointer causes undefined behavior; references are not guaranteed to have the same characteristics as pointers.

Comment: The last argument you used allowed the GC heap to be corrupted by the native code.  It *must* be a StringBuilder (not ref) with a sufficiently large capacity.  And be sure to pass its Capacity in the 3rd argument.  -1 to be on the safe side.

Comment: @cdhowie: I am uncertain what MIC_Open does with the pointer. They do not specify in the API documentation, nor do I have access to the underlying source code.

What would you suggest I replace ref ulong with?

Comment: @HansPassant: Do I understand correctly: I should use StringBuilder instead of String in the 4th argument? I will try replacing the 4th argument with `[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string` with `[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr] StringBuilder`, and make the required changes where I call the marshalled functions. I will report back with the results.

Comment: See the solution I posted below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Juderb You cannot portably invoke C++ code from C# for multiple reasons, and in this case because a reference is used.  The CLR has no way to know how references are implemented in your particular C++ compiler.  The portable thing to do would be to write a C++ library that exposes a C glue function (via `extern "C"`) that accepts a pointer and passes the target to this `MIC_Open` function as a reference.

Comment: Not going to lie @cdhowie, I do not understand what you are saying, but I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Hans Passant for his recommendation. I corrected the marshalling as follows:

```
[DllImport("/filepath/Ni_Mic_Driver.dll")]
protected static extern int MIC_Open ( int deviceIndex , ref ulong accessoryMask , uint errorMessageMaxSize , [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder errorString);
```

I then use this method as follows (simplified here for display):

```
NikonDefinitions.accessory = 0;
int errorMessageCapacity = 256;
int nikonErrorMessageMaxSize = errorMessageCapacity - 1;
StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder(errorMessageCapacity);
int nikonReturn = NikonDefinitions.MIC_Open(Convert.ToInt32(1),ref NikonDefinitions.accessory,nikonErrorMessageMaxSize,errorMessage);
```

Comment: you should set the capacity in the stringbuilder constructor, to be sure it has actually 256 chars capacity.

Comment: @speising, is that necessary if you do not know ahead of time how many characters will actually be in the string. The 256 is an arbitrary max size, as the API does not indicate a suggested max size.

Comment: @Juderb It's necessary because if the capacity is very small then you may not be able to get full diagnostic information back out (the error message would be truncated).  You need to pre-allocate enough space by setting the `StringBuilder` capacity.  If you pass in 256 without actually setting the capacity on the `StringBuilder` to 257 then the unmanaged code will receive a pointer to a much smaller buffer and could overrun it, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @speising: The API method requires the 3rd argument to be uint32. It cannot except a value of -1, as Hans suggested.

Comment: @cdhowie: I will go ahead and set the capacity to `errorMessageMaxSize+1`. This will have to do, as the API provides no indication of what a reasonable value for the buffer size would be.

Comment: jeez. "capacity-1". eg stringbuilder(256) -> 255

Comment: If the "jeez" is in reference to the API providing crappy documentation, I agree with you @speising.

Comment: Also, @speising, does it really matter if I set the StringBuilder capacity to errorMesssageMaxSize+1 with errorMessageMaxSize=255, or do the inverse and set errorMessageMaxSize to capacity-1? Is there a difference besides convention? Understandly, it would be awkward, but not incorrect, to set errorMessageMaxSize to 256 and end up with a StringBuilder capacity of 257.